# Записать строку чисел 12.25,14.25,23.25, в array input js

Tags: javascript

Есть строка 
    `117.75,40.75,36.75,23.5,15.75,11,9.25,8,4.5,4,3.75,2.5,2.5,2,2,2,2,2,1.5,1.25,1.25,0.75,0.75,0.75,0.75,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,`

Как можно записать в массив input числа в этом порядке.

`<input type="text" class="count_quantity_product">`

`<input type="text" class="count_quantity_product" value="117.75">
 <input type="text" class="count_quantity_product" value="40.75"> 
 <input type="text" class="count_quantity_product" value="36.75">
 <input type="text" class="count_quantity_product" value="23.75">`

Comment: Создать глобальную переменную, получить элемент по классу, перебором через forEach добавить в переменную значение

Comment: Вам нужно разбить строку и создать массив input'ов с значениями из разделенной строки?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = '117.75,40.75,36.75,23.5,15.75,11,9.25,8,4.5,4,3.75,2.5,2.5,2,2,2,2,2,1.5,1.25,1.25,0.75,0.75,0.75,0.75,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5';

function createInput(val) {
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.classList.add('count_quantity_product');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.value = val;
  
  return input;
}

const inputsArray = str.split(',').map(createInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = "117.75,40.75,36.75,23.5,15.75,11,9.25,8,4.5,4,3.75,2.5,2.5,2,2,2,2,2,1.5,1.25,1.25,0.75,0.75,0.75,0.75,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5";
let b = a.split(',');
b.forEach((i) => {
  let inp = document.createElement("INPUT");
  inp.setAttribute("value", i);
  inp.setAttribute("class", "count_quantity_product");
  document.body.appendChild(inp);
})
```

Как то так...